# Query regarding Difference between JavaScript Object And JSOn Object

Tags: javascript, json

Here is my question:
 in java script:
we hav an object:

```
var someObject={"name":"somename"};
```

Now we want to get the name ,we ll do

```
alert(someObject.name); //it will print somename Right?
```

Same object i get from a source which sends a JSON object as

```
someJSONObject={"name":"someName"};
```

Now in my javascript code ,without parsing this someJSONObject ,i can get name as

```
alert(someJSONObject.name);
```

If it is so ,why we need to convert JSON Object to a javaScript Object by parsing it ,when we can use it as an object without parsing or using `eval()`?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Because it's not a JSON Object. The syntax `{"name":"someName"}`, with quoted keys, does not make it JSON, the same syntax is supported by Javascript object literals.

JSON can be embedded in Javascript strings. Like:

```
var json = '{"key": "value"}';
```

Then you can parse it into Javascript data types:

```
var obj = JSON.parse( json );
```

Note that `eval` may cause syntax errors because the syntaxes of JSON and Javascript are not ultimately compatible. The above would have caused a syntax error if `evaled`.

Comment: thanks for the reply .But when i can use JSONobject received from server in the same way as my normal javascript object,why we have to parse it and make it to a javascript object ?Why parsing is necessary if all the operations can be performed without it ?

Comment: @user2110167 Are you talking about embedding it inside `<script>` element? Then it is evaluated as Javascript code, and it might work depending on many factors.

Comment: i have a javascript function which receives a JSON object from Java code .If i don't parse that JSON object received and try to access the keys inside it ,i am able to do that .

Comment: @user2110167 If you are embedding JSON serialization inside Javascript context, then it will be evaluated as Javascript. Because of the 99.99% compatible syntax, it will work.

Comment: I was just confused between the two form of objects,because they look same too.Sorry for asking such a silly question.Thanks

Comment: @user2110167 There is no difference when interpreted as Javascript in this case.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a `string`, so it's something like `var jsonObject = '{"name":"someName"}';` an `object` is an object.

Comment: Fine jsonObject is a string,then if i try to acces the name inside it ,i can simply do jsonObject.name .Why we need to parse it then ?

Comment: Well no, you can't access it via jsonObject.name. THat's the point

Comment: @Mchl You are right.i tried that and its a difference between the two .Thanks